# Issues (and spec check) regarding terminating solid core ethernet cable

Tags: cable, power-over-ethernet

Tomorrow I'm installing a [TP-Link TL-SG1008MP](https://www.amazon.co.uk/TL-SG1008MP-Ethernet-RackMount-Configuration-Required/dp/B07Q5B51P7/) 8-Port Gigabit PoE+ Ethernet Switch to an existing network, powering a [TP-Link OC200](https://www.amazon.co.uk/TP-Link-OC200-Omada-Cloud-Controller/dp/B07GT8QSRW) Omada AP controller and three [TP-Link EAP225-Outdoor](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Wireless-Waterproof-Installation-Controller-EAP110-Outdoor/dp/B07C217N5V) access points powered over 802.3af Power over Ethernet.

Ahead of the install the client has had their team run three cables out to the locations for the APs, each 50m or shorter, from a reel and self-terminating the connections (spot where the issue probably is...!)

According to their RJ45 tester, the first of these cables run today was terminated at both ends (and also tested with existing switch and a laptop) with no connection, no test pass.

I spec'd [Connectix Cat6a External F/FTP LDPE Solid core ethernet cable](https://www.cablemonkey.co.uk/cat6a-cable/13868-cat6a-external-u-ftp-cable-ldpe-outer-sheath.html#/33-length-100mt) from Cablemonkey (UK) and also the matching '[CCS Cat6a FTP RJ45 Plug](https://www.cablemonkey.co.uk/cat6a-accessories/14249-ccs-cat6a-ftp-rj45-plug-for-sold-core-cable.html) - For Solid Cable' from Cablemonkey.

1. Is there anything obviously wrong with that spec of cable / plugs? In reading up I wanted solid core for a long run carrying POE;
2. Is crimping plugs to solid core cable reasonably standard? The supplier had these available and mentioned compatibility, so while I haven't seen if it was a bad job in person yet, I'm wondering if I've recommended the right thing for terminating as opposed to a punch-in terminal and a patch cable to the switch / AP; what other options are there?
3. If using a punch-in or similar connector for this kind of use to bridge to a patch cable at either end, does that pose an issue with disrupting the power supply i.e. POE?

Grateful for any suggestions / sanity checking!

Wiring diagram provided to client:
[image: Wiring diagram provided to client]

Comment: If you use shielded cable, it must be [properly grounded at least on each end, and the shield must be continuous from end-to-end](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/42217/8499). Also, the [required cable category tests](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/42697/8499) requires a very expensive tester. This is not a DIY project, and even experienced installer have problems with Category-6 and Category-6a cabling. Solid-core cable gets punched down, and stranded cabling uses the plugs, doing the opposite will not work correctly.

Comment: There are other problems that can happen in installation. For example, exceeding the minimum bend radius or maximum pulling tension can permanently ruin a cable, especially a solid-core cable.

Comment: Thanks Ron, I do appreciate your replies. I wondered as solid-core is typically punched down, any idea as to why suppliers offer RJ45 plug terminations that claim to be for solid core? I'd be especially grateful for any thoughts you might have on point 3 - i.e. whether a proper termination to e.g. a properly grounded face plate / back box and patch cable from there would pose an issue from the perspective of 802.3af equipment.

Comment: The grounding has nothing to do with PoE. Improperly grounded or shielded cable will be worse than UTP cabling as the shield will cause interference. That is explained in the first link of my first comment. In any case, you really need a proper (expensive) cable tester to see if the cabling passes the category test suite. Solid-core cabling is fragile, which is why it is permanently punched down as it cannot take a lot of movement. Stranded is less fragile and used for patch cables, but the performance is poor. That is why the 100 meters is 90 meters of solid-core and 10 meters of stranded.

Comment: Does the existing network support Cat6 cabling? I've had problems with Cat6 cables on Cat5e hardware before.

Comment: For your Gigabit Ethernet hardware, Cat 5e is perfectly fine and much less sensitive (still neds proper installation certification though).

Comment: @Mast It's hard to tell from its documentation, but direct connection to a [Netgear JGS516PE switch](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/JGS516PE.aspx) would have been part of their testing

Comment: @Zac67 thanks for the recommend - it sounds like they might have a reel of this available and that's 802.3af compatible

Comment: I'd also strongly suggest using either a patch panel or wall sockets with punch down. Also, there are "field-configurable" plugs with punch down. Simple crimping adapters would need to *perfectly* fit the solid-core cable to actually work. I'd avoid them or at least have the vendor guarantee that that exact plug/cable combination works. Additionally, you likely need special tooling for them.